# java.classpath error in using umlgraph

Tags: ant, javadoc

I am following [Meera Subbarao](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u?page=1) to create java docs using [umlgraph](http://www.umlgraph.org) but getting this error message:

> build.xml: Reference java.classpath not found.

Could somebody help me find what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for helping me out.

My ant target is:

```
<target name="javadocs" description="generates javadoc and also UML Diagram">
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}/javadoc"/>
    <javadoc sourcepath="${src.dir}"
             packagenames="com.myproject.*"
             destdir="${reports.dir}/javadoc"
             classpathref="java.classpath"
             private="true">
        <doclet name="org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc" path="lib/UMLGraph.jar">
            <param name="-attributes" />
            <param name="-operations" />
            <param name="-qualify" />
            <param name="-types" />
            <param name="-visibility" />
        </doclet>
    </javadoc>
    <apply executable="dot" dest="${reports.dir}" parallel="false">
        <arg value="-Tpng"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <targetfile/>
        <srcfile/>
        <fileset dir="${reports.dir}" includes="*.dot"/>
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.dot" to="*.png"/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error message here is this attribute on your javadoc element: `classpathref="java.classpath"`.

To use this, you have to define a `path` element in your build file with `id="java.classpath"`, like this:

```
<path id="java.classpath">
   ...
</path>
```

Comment: oh, I was thinking perhaps it is system variable. Thank you for help

Comment: For system properties, use `classpath="${java.classpath}"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, it's best to create a 'path id', and then refer to this path id within the javadoc doclet section via the keyword 'pathref'  ..

example path id (use pathelement to point to the location of jar file):

```
<path id="umlgraph.doclet.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${supplementary.lib.dir}/UmlGraph.jar"/>
</path>
```

then in the javadoc doclet section:

```
<doclet name="org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc" pathref="umlgraph.doclet.classpath">
```

That ought to work ..